# Call api and update database every 30 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have to call an api for every field in a database every 30 minutes and update the response in the respective fields.

```csharp
string Shorten(string url)
{
    url = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
    string reqUri = String.Format(@"http://example.com/api.php?longurl={0}", url);

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqUri);
    req.Timeout = 5000;
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you asking how to trigger the above code every 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes scott, i want to trigger this c# code every 30 minutes and update the results in my database

Comment: There are many different task scheduling platforms; .NET does not have any built-in.